# Can't use System.Management.Automation in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'd made a simple C# console app in Visual Studio 2019.
I would like to use the Automation.dll so I installed the Automation package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation

I sat the System.Management.Automation using but it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error (translated from German)

> CS0234 The type or namespace name "Automation" does not exist in the namespace "System.Management". An assembly reference may be missing.

Comment: Is that package definitely installed in the project? Which version?

Comment: Which Framework are you on? .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: yes. v7.0.3. I can see it in the nuget package manager.

Comment: I am using the .Net Framework 4.6.1. There is no "core". Is that the problem maybe?

Comment: Not completely sure, but it looks like it. Under "Dependencies" there's only ".NETCoreApp 3.1" ... so I guess, it's only available for Core 3.1

Comment: @Fildor. It works! :D I love you. Can we get married? Have a nice day :)

Comment: LOL, already taken ... glad to help. Hau rein!